# Converting C Code Into Assembly Mips Language

Tags: c, assembly, mips

Hi so I am brand new to the whole MIPS assembly code and am trying to teach myself with online help sources. I can understand some parts of it and how it works. My problem that I need to solve now is

```
int A[50], B[50]; 
for (i=1; i < 50; i++) { 
 A[i] = A[i] + B[i-1] / A[i-1]; 
}
```

Some tips and pointers would very much be appreciated looking to expand my knowledge. I've tried those online things but don't seem to help me learn.

Comment: *I've tried those online things but don't seem to help me learn* - so what do you expect to get here? By "online things" you mean some online c-to-mips translators?

Comment: You can have a look at how compilers translate your code into assembly. Don’t forget to turn optimizations off, otherwise any compiler will optimize the heck of your code)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes the c-mips. In not looking for someone to do it for me, some people are new to this (me) and so i dont think the attitude is needed. Just looking for what would be my best bet going about this

Comment: Looking at compiler output is usually your best bet.  @ForceBru: There's not much to optimize here, and `-O0` code is really noisy and hard to follow (full of store/reload). https://godbolt.org/z/RbYSsR from gcc (for MIPS II) and clang (for MIPS32r6) are pretty reasonable.  The `teq` is a trap-on-equal to catch division by zero.  If targeting baseline MIPS I, it uses a conditional branch over a  `break` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the compilers translate this kind of code.
This is C code, but it is strictly equivalent to your original code and it is written in such a way that every C instruction can be mapped to an asm instruction. I have even written which instruction should be used.

```
int * pA=&A[0];     // mov
int * pB=&B[0];     // mov
int i=1;            // addi
int n=50;           // addi
do{
  // body of for loop
  int B_1=*(pB-1) ; // lw
  int A_1=*(pA-1) ; // lw
  int D=B_1/A1;     // div
  int A=*pA;        // lw
  A += D;           // add
  *pA = A;          // sw
  // increment part of the loop
  i+=1;             // addi
  pA+=1;            // addi
  pb+=1;            // addi
  // test part of the loop
  while (i<N);      // blt -> do
 }
```

You just have to pick a register for all the variables (for instance, choose to copy `pA` in `$t3` (or `r4` or whatever), and figure out how to translate this instruction in asm. Look at MIPS documentation and translation should be easy.

There are though a couple of important things to know.

1. Pointers are similar to memory addresses that are manipulated by the processor, except when increment (or in general pointer arithmetic) is concerned. If `p` is a pointer to an element of type `T` in C, `p++` means that `p` will point to the next element of type `T`. For adresses, the *size* of the type must be considered. If an `int` is 4 bytes, "point to next int" will correspond to "add to address the size of an int" (ie 4).
2. `lw` and `sw` use based addressing, that is they can add an immediate to an address. Pointer arithmetic is also relevant. So if `p` is an `int` pointer, and you want to implement `x=*(p+2)`, assuming `x` is in `$t4` and `p` is in `$t7`, you have to do `lw $t4,8($t7)` that means read memory at address `$t7+8` (as `8==2*sizeof(int)`.

It should not be too difficult to write a first code. Then, you can try to optimize it. Maybe loading `A[i-1]` at every iteration is not useful, for instance? Maybe you can reduce the number of variables (registers)?